# String.fromCharCode vs output from &#(charcode);

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why I would see a difference in output between using `String.fromCharCode(charcode)` and printing out `&#charcode;` for codes between 127 and 160?  It seems looking on firefox, chrome, mac/win and ie the output for both are the same for thousands of other values but not the codes in that range.  Outputting a string from `fromCharCode()` creates missing characters in that range.

Here's some source if you want to specifically encounter this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/loose.dtd">
<HTML LANG="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<META name="author" content="(cogknight@yahoo.com)">
<META name="date" content="Tue Oct 25 02:35:44 CDT 2011">  
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
BODY { font-family: helvetica, sans-serif; }
table { border: 1px solid black; }
td { border: 1px solid black; }
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function init()
{
   var elem = document.getElementById('msg');
   var msg = "<TABLE STYLE='border:1px solid black;'>";
   msg += "<tr><th>code</th><th>fromCharCode</th><th>ampersand</th></tr>";
   var ccode = 0;
   for (;ccode < 180; ccode++)
   {
      msg += "<TR><TD>";
      msg += ccode;
      msg += "</TD><TD>";
      msg += String.fromCharCode(ccode);
      msg += "</TD><TD>";
      msg += "&#" + ccode + ";";
      msg += "</TD</TR>";
   }
   msg += "</TABLE>";

   elem.innerHTML = msg;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV ID="msg">
</DIV>
<SCRIPT>
init();
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks for you time,
BBB

Answer (score 0):

I verified your output on http://jsfiddle.net/E8S9J/ at least for a Mac running Chrome and also on Firefox.

The right hand column is showing output for the evil Windows-1252 character set.

You can see the issues for characters in the range 0x80-0x9F (128-159) here: http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT

Interesting that the JavaScript `String.fromCharCode` produces the proper characters from the code, but the HTML entity does not.  Browsers just do this, even though they probably should not.  Here is an explanation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSpecial_characters):

> Use an HTML numeric character reference like ¡. Some old browsers incorrectly interpret codes in the range 128–159 as references to the native character set; however, a numerical character reference is the only way in HTML to enter special characters for which there are no named entities, such as the Turkish letters. Because the code points 128 through 159 are not used for displayable glyphs in either ISO-8859-1 and Unicode, character references in that range (such as ƒ) are illegal in HTML and ambiguous, though they are commonly used by many web sites. Almost all browsers treat ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252, which does have printable characters in that space, and they often found their way into article titles on English projects, which really caused confusion when trying to create interwiki links to said pages.

I think the browser manufacturers do this because they figure so many web authors do not understand character encodings and are going to use the Windows-1252 set anyway (gotta slap those old MS Word docs "on the web").  HTML is by nature very very tolerant.  It tries to do its best even when the markup is all whacked.  Using entities in that range (hey they are control characters after all) is kind of messy, so the tolerant browser shows what it can, *even if it has to show glyphs from a character set the author did not want*.

Answer (score 0):

128-159 aren't unicode characters.

My best guess: In javascript-land, characters are interpreted as utf-16, so 128-159 are sort of "legal non-characters". In HTML-land, utf-8 is king (assuming you're using utf-8), so [the last bit of a single-byte character must *always* be zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Design), this means those characters can only go as high as 127 (kind of like having a sign bit). If you want to check, you can see that '10000000' in binary is equal to 128.

So, in utf-8, having a character in the 128-159 range is impossible due to the mechanics of the encoding. In utf-16, it is possible to *represent* a character in that range, even though no characters exist in that range.

Comment: No, this answer is incorrect.  There ARE characters in the Unicode character set in 128-159 (U+0080-U+009F).  See http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf; they are there, plain as day.  Also UTF-8 encodes them perfectly well. They are encoded in two bytes, not one.  The only thing you can say is that the characters are not printable.

Comment: Alright fine, there are unicode characters in that range. My answer is still correct regardless of semantics. 128-159 are not __representable__ in utf-8, which is what any modern HTML parser would be likely to use. They are however representable in utf-16 (js). edit: If you noticed, I also made it a point to say *single-byte*.

Comment: That's cool but that wasn't clear to me from the wording.... I read the phrase "having a character in the 128-159 range is impossible" as meaning UTF-8 was somehow deficient and you really should edit out the line that says "128-159 are not unicode characters."  Regardless if you think about it, nothing in this problem has anything to do with single-byte or multi-byte encodings.  Whether you use UTF-8 or ISO8859-1 or ASCII or UTF-32, browsers will still render a `&#131;` as a florin.  This is completely independent of how the ampersand, hash, digits and semicolon are encoded.